# Modified Union Find Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, union-find

The task is to make data structure with the following operations:

query: takes two arguments s and t and returns true if they are in the same set and false otherwise.

union: takes two arguments s and t and creates a union of the two sets that contain s and t such that if s is in S and t is in T it removes S and T and replaces it with the union of S and T.

move: takes two arguments s and t and takes s out of its current set and moves s and only s to the set containing t.

union and move don't do anything if s and t are in the same set.

My question is: how do you make an efficient version of this data structure that is < O(n²)?

Comment: If everything but the last line is a third party task, please put in a block quote and [tell who originated it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and how you came to know it.

Comment: It's homework. I wouldn't know how

Comment: What's $n$? Is it the number of elements in your universe? Is the goal really that of implementing each operation in $o(n^2)$ time?

Answer (score 1):

You want Union-Find with deletions (Kaplan et al. 2002, and Alstrup et al. 2005).  You can do deletion in constant time, but it's non-trivial.